# How to reference *.jar files in wsgen classpath

Tags: web-services, ant

I'm having trouble defining my classpath using wsgen in an ANT file.

```
    <target name="wsgen">
    <property name="wsgen_cp" value="./build/classes/" /> 

    <echo message="classpath is : ${wsgen_cp}"/>
    <exec executable="wsgen">
        <!-- Classpath -->
        <arg value="-verbose" />            
        <arg value="-classpath" />
        <arg value="${wsgen_cp}" />
        <!-- Sortie des sources -->
        <arg value="-d" />
        <arg value="${project.build.dir}/build/generated/"/>
        <arg value="-r" /> 
        <arg value="${project.build.dir}/build/wsdl"/>
        <arg value="-s" />
        <arg value="${project.build.dir}/build/sources"/>
        <!-- Classes de WebServices -->
        <arg value="-keep" />
        <arg value="rpm.patient.wsimpl.RpmPatientInterfaceImpl" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Once I run the target, I get the following error:

```
[exec] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rpm/patient/RpmPatientInterface
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
 [exec]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 [exec]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsgenOptions.getClass(WsgenOptions.java:287)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsgenOptions.validateEndpointClass(WsgenOptions.java:223)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsgenOptions.validate(WsgenOptions.java:214)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(WsgenTool.java:110)
 [exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 [exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:120)
 [exec]     at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsGen.main(WsGen.java:42)
 [exec] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rpm.patient.RpmPatientInterface
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 [exec]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 [exec]     ... 21 more
```

When I append the corresponding jar to my classpath (where resides rpm/patient/RpmPatientInterface):

It seems that the classpath is invalid since it doesn't find the file I'm trying to generate my stubs from:
     [exec] Class not found: "rpm.patient.wsimpl.RpmPatientInterfaceImpl"
     [exec] Usage: WSGEN [options]

Any hints that could help me?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am interested in referencing *.jar files with wsgen.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with a legacy system which I don't know how to generate the WSDL as well. It contains maven librarys, I have to include them one by one in the `-cp` argument, I can't use wildcard like `java -cp lib/*` command, not sure why. Anyway, hope below helps:

> D:\MyData\Software\JavaJDK\bin\wsgen -verbose -keep -cp
>   "spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar;spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar;D:/my-xxx-project/target/classes"
>   com.xxx.ws.webservice.xxxImpl -wsdl

I am executing this in the `target/lib` path, contains all the maven jars. `D:/my-xxx-project/target/classes` contains all the Java Classes.

For your case, you just need to add in multiple jars file path (separate with `;`) in:

> `<property name="wsgen_cp" value="./build/classes/" />`